# Data table error could not find function "."

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to run the following piece of code. Whenever I try to run the code I get the following error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."`
How can I fix it? Could someone help?

```
data(mtcars)
library(data.table)
mtcarsDT <- data.table(mtcars)
mtcarsDT[ mpg > 20,
        .(AvgHP = mean(hp),
        "MinWT(kg)" = min(wt * 453.6)), # wt lbs
        by = .(cyl, under5gears = gear < 5)
        ]
```

Here is the session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8    htmltools_0.2.6 plyr_1.8.1      Rcpp_0.11.3     reshape2_1.4.1  rmarkdown_0.3.3 stringr_0.6.2  
[8] tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: Please try from a clean session of R. Also provide the `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I don't see the `data.table` package.

Comment: I reinstalled the package and it shows up in the sessionInfo now but still the error is there.

Comment: This problem seems to occur with `data.table_1.9.2`. It doesn't appear with `data.table_1.9.4`.

Comment: When I install package using `install.packages` it automatically installs 1.9.2 version. Could you say, how I can specify to install 1.9.4?

Comment: Are you on -nix system? You can always download the latest source and compile on your own.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, its is "x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0", i.e. OSX SnowLeopard. According to [this page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_data.table.html), there is an error during the compilation of version 1.9.4 on this OS.

Comment: It was implemented in 1.9.4. The errors there are tests related to `xts` package (and IIRC they happened because `xts` was also updated around the same time) - so they really aren't errors. You can just install 1.9.4 from source.

Comment: @Arun As already pointed out, there is a compilation error for version 1.9.4 on SnowLeopard.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. What's the compilation error <you> get? The link you point to doesn't have any *compilation errors* - just some tests fail (for which I've explained the reason).

Comment: I guess if the OP tries to compile on is SnowLeopard the version 1.9.4, it will fail. And this is the reason why only version 1.9.2 is available on CRAN for SnowLeopard.

Comment: @Pascal, you'll have to tag me, else I don't see your message. In that case, you can always download the source file, and install it from source by specifying the path to the source file.

Comment: @Pascal: This succeeds on an SL build of R (with the proper XCode and Command Line Tools): `install.packages("data.table", type="source", dependencies=TRUE)` and after using `unloadNamespace` on pkgs: 'data.table', 'reshape2' and 'plyr' (in that order, I am able to load version 1.9.4 and run that code.

Comment: Thank you @BondedDust. Good news for the OP.

Comment: @42- maybe worth posting that as an answer. I had this exact issue on macOS 10.12 with `data.table` version 1.10 after upgrading from R 3.3 to 3.4, your solution solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the instructions I offered 2.5 years ago are still current for people using out-of-date versions of Mac R. Assuming you have Xcode and the Command Line Tools installed, you need to first either a) restart R (without loading any of the versions of data.table., reshape2, and dplyr), or b)  remove any loaded Namespaces that might conflict with the ability to test-load the new packages:

```
unloadNamespace('data.table')
unloadNamespace('reshape2')
unloadNamespace('plyr')
```

Then build from source:

```
install.packages("data.table", type="source", dependencies=TRUE)
```

The reason that building from source might work when installing a binary package might not is that the former strategy gets you better checking for version dependencies.