# R: merge based on multiple conditions (with non-equal criteria)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge 2 data frames based on multiple conditions.

```
DF1 <- data.frame("col1" = rep(c("A","B"), 18),
                  "col2" = rep(c("C","D","E"), 12),
                  "value"= (sample(1:100,36)),
                  "col4" = rep(NA,36))

DF2 <- data.frame("col1" = rep("A",6),
                  "col2" = rep(c("C","D"),3),
                  "data" = rep(c(1,3),3),
                  "min" = seq(0,59,by=10),
                  "max" = seq(10,69,by=10))


> DF1
   col1 col2 value col4
1     A    C    22   NA
2     B    D    58   NA
3     A    E    35   NA
4     B    C    86   NA
5     A    D    37   NA
6     B    E    16   NA
7     A    C    46   NA
8     B    D    23   NA
9     A    E    88   NA
10    B    C     3   NA
11    A    D    33   NA
12    B    E    25   NA
13    A    C    19   NA
14    B    D    24   NA
15    A    E     9   NA
16    B    C    76   NA
17    A    D    62   NA
18    B    E    68   NA
19    A    C    97   NA
20    B    D    43   NA
21    A    E     8   NA
22    B    C    84   NA
23    A    D    36   NA
24    B    E    20   NA
25    A    C    57   NA
26    B    D    99   NA
27    A    E    42   NA
28    B    C    64   NA
29    A    D    87   NA
30    B    E     1   NA
31    A    C    78   NA
32    B    D    34   NA
33    A    E    41   NA
34    B    C    32   NA
35    A    D    10   NA
36    B    E    72   NA

> DF2
  col1 col2 data min max
1    A    C    1   0  10
2    A    D    3  10  20
3    A    C    1  20  30
4    A    D    3  30  40
5    A    C    1  40  50
6    A    D    3  50  60
```

DF1 is the main table and DF2 is treated as a lookup table

If col1 and col2 of DF1 match that of DF2, and 'value' of DF1 is in between min and max of DF2, then column 'data' from DF2 will be added to DF1. If the conditions are not met, 'data' of DF1 will have value of NA.

Expected output (first 6 rows):

```
  col1 col2 value col4 data
1    A    C    22   NA    1
2    B    D    58   NA   NA
3    A    E    35   NA   NA
4    B    C    86   NA   NA
5    A    D    37   NA    3
6    B    E    16   NA   NA
```

I've tried using merge (to match col1 snd col2) then subset (to filter only rows that have value in between min and max) , but my goal is to maintain all the rows of DF1.

Anyone has an idea on this ?

Comment: can you share what your expected output looks like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complexe non-equi merge in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043047/complexe-non-equi-merge-in-r)

Comment: @Tushar please see edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data, changing `stringsAsFactors=F`

```
DF1 <- data.frame("col1" = rep(c("A","B"), 18),
              "col2" = rep(c("C","D","E"), 12),
              "value"= (sample(1:100,36)),
              "col4" = rep(NA,36),
              stringsAsFactors=F)

DF2 <- data.frame("col1" = rep("A",6),
              "col2" = rep(c("C","D"),3),
              "data" = rep(c(1,3),3),
              "min" = seq(0,59,by=10),
              "max" = seq(10,69,by=10),
              stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Using `dplyr`, *1)* merge the two data using `left_join`, *2)* check `ifelse` `value` is `between` `min` and `max` `rowwise`, then *3)* unselect `min` and `max` columns...

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(DF1, DF2, by=c("col1","col2")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(data = ifelse(between(value,min,max), data, NA)) %>%
  select(-min, -max)
```

*Not sure if you were expecting to perform some kind of aggregation*, but here's the output of the above code

```
    col1  col2 value  col4  data
 1     A     C    23    NA    NA
 2     A     C    23    NA     1
 3     A     C    23    NA    NA
 4     B     D    59    NA    NA
 5     A     E    57    NA    NA
 6     B     C     8    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 6):

With the recent versions of `data.table`, *non-equi joins* and *update on join* are possible:

```
library(data.table)
head(setDT(DF1)[setDT(DF2), on = c("col1", "col2", "value>=min", "value<=max"), 
                data := data])
```

> ```
>    rn col1 col2 value col4 data
> 1:  1    A    C    22   NA    1
> 2:  2    B    D    58   NA   NA
> 3:  3    A    E    35   NA   NA
> 4:  4    B    C    86   NA   NA
> 5:  5    A    D    37   NA    3
> 6:  6    B    E    16   NA   NA
> ```

#### Data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(rn = 1:36, col1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B"), col2 = c("C", "D", "E", "C", "D", "E", "C", 
"D", "E", "C", "D", "E", "C", "D", "E", "C", "D", "E", "C", "D", 
"E", "C", "D", "E", "C", "D", "E", "C", "D", "E", "C", "D", "E", 
"C", "D", "E"), value = c(22L, 58L, 35L, 86L, 37L, 16L, 46L, 
23L, 88L, 3L, 33L, 25L, 19L, 24L, 9L, 76L, 62L, 68L, 97L, 43L, 
8L, 84L, 36L, 20L, 57L, 99L, 42L, 64L, 87L, 1L, 78L, 34L, 41L, 
32L, 10L, 72L), col4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("rn", 
"col1", "col2", "value", "col4"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
DF2 <- structure(list(rn = 1:6, col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
), col2 = c("C", "D", "C", "D", "C", "D"), data = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L), min = c(0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L), max = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L)), .Names = c("rn", "col1", "col2", "data", 
"min", "max"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) which wraps *fuzzyjoin* functions, you can do :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
debugonce(safe_left_join)

safe_left_join(DF1, DF2,  ~
                  X("col1") == Y("col1") & 
                  X("col2") == Y("col2") & 
                  X("value") >= Y("min") &
                  X("value") <= Y("max"),
               conflict = ~.x) %>% 
  head(15)
#    col1 col2 value col4 data min max
# 1     A    C    90   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 2     B    D    20   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 3     A    E     8   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 4     B    C    99   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 5     A    D    42   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 6     B    E    37   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 7     A    C    47   NA    1  40  50
# 8     B    D    61   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 9     A    E    55   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 10    B    C    11   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 11    A    D    81   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 12    B    E    48   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 13    A    C    77   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 14    B    D    58   NA   NA  NA  NA
# 15    A    E     3   NA   NA  NA  NA
```

The `conflict` argument here tells the function to return only the conflicted columns from the lhs (`col1` and `col2`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

```
final <- merge(DF1,DF2,by=c("col1","col2"),all.x = T)
final$data <- ifelse(final$data>=final$min & final$data<=final$max,final$data,"NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

By using all.x=TRUE all rows of DF1 are kept then adjust condition in filter as follows:

```
iMed=merge(DF1,DF2,by.x=c('col1','col2'),by.y=c('col1','col2'),all.x=TRUE)
Res=iMed[is.na(iMed[,'min'])|is.na(iMed[,'max'])|(iMed[,'value']<=iMed[,'max'] & iMed[,'value']>=iMed[,'min'] ),]
```