# Temporal join in R

Tags: r

I have two tables called `dates` and `items`:

```
#dates table
from <- c(as.Date("2022/1/1"), as.Date("2022/3/1"), as.Date("2022/5/1"))
to <- c(as.Date("2022/1/25"), as.Date("2022/3/17"), as.Date("2022/5/30"))
id <- c(1,1,2)
dates <- data.frame(from, to, id)

#items table
item_id <- c(1, 1, 2)
date <- c(as.Date("2022/1/5"), as.Date("2022/3/4"), as.Date("2022/1/4"))
items <-data.frame(item_id, date)

#end result
from <- c(as.Date("2022/1/1"), as.Date("2022/3/1"), NA)
to <- c(as.Date("2022/1/25"), as.Date("2022/3/17"), NA)

end_result <- data.frame(item_id, date, from, to)
```

The `dates` df needs to join onto the `items` df where the id's match and also where the date from the `items` df is inbetween the from and to dates from the `dates` df. The `end_result` dataframe shows the expected results.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand the example. Also, I am unsure about the expected output. Can you please specify? Maybe, including a few more rows helps me. I have the feeling you want something else; wild guess: `x = cbind(dates, date = items$date); x$flag = vapply(seq(nrow(x)), \(i) ifelse(date[i] %in% seq(x$from[i], x$to[i], "days"), 1L, 0L), integer(1L)); x = x[x$flag == 1L, ]`

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043047/complex-non-equi-merge-in-r) for a `data.table` approach.

Comment: Please show expect output.

Comment: added the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) sqldf** Left join items to dates using the indicated join criteria.  from and to are SQL reserved words so put them in square brackets.

```
library(sqldf)

result <- sqldf("select items.item_id, items.date, dates.[from], dates.[to]
  from items left join dates on dates.id = items.item_id and
    items.date between dates.[from] and dates.[to]")

# check
identical(result, end_result)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) dplyr**  This works in the same way.

```
library(dplyr)

result2 <- items %>%
  left_join(dates, join_by(item_id == id, between(date, from, to)))

# check
identical(result2, end_result)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution, which has the advantage of avoiding an extra copy of the entire data by updating `items` in-place instead, as well as typically being extremely fast:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(items)[dates,
             on = .(item_id == id, date >= from, date <= to),
             `:=` (from = from, to = to)]
```

If instead you want to assign to a new table `end_result`, start with `end_result <- as.data.table(items)[` instead of `setDT(items)[`.